# making a python interpreter using javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I want to make a python interpreter by using Javascript.

Then you can input the python code and the Javascript in the webpage can interpret the code into javascript code and then run the code and return the result.

Because I have not much experience in this area, so I want some advice from the senior.

Thanks very much ...

Comment: Better send script to server side and run python code in a controlled environment.

Comment: Your page is on site or just local application?

Comment: It is a good idea, but i want to use javascript itself to interpret the python code...just like some project in github which uses javascript to interpret the javascript...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pypyjs](https://github.com/pypyjs/pypyjs), and the detailed procedure is also available.

Comment: The most recent release for this project is dated July 2015 and its github hasn't had any code commits for 6 years. Its Readme suggests to go to Pyodide [link](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide) which is currently active.

Answer (score 2):

There are many interpreters and source-to-source compilers that can convert Python to JavaScript. The [Skulpt](https://skulpt.org/) interpreter allows Python source code to run in a web browser on the client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Well, an interpreter is not really a job for a beginner, also you'd better send the code to server side with AJAX, and then display the result in the page.